# How do I avoid overlapping header and first sentence of the page while using fancyhdr?

Tags: spacing, header-footer, fancyhdr, rules

I am using `fancyhdr` to put some header and footnote in my document but from second page onward, the first line of the page and the header are overlapping like the following. How can I resolve this?

[image]

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,lefttitle]{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, natbib=true, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage[margin=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec} %for making section tiny


\pagestyle{fancy}% Change page style to fancy
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[L]{Research Proposal}
\fancyhead[R]{Ishfaq, Haque}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
% \fancyfoot[R]{ISHHA2001}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Default \headrulewidth is 0.4pt
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% Default \footrulewidth is 0pt


% \definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{185,95,71}
% \definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{185,105,71}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{185,76,71}
% \definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{221,110,78}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
% \begin{flushleft}
%   \textbf{\@title}
% \end{flushleft}
\begin{flushright}
%   \@author
\end{flushright}
\egroup
}
\makeatother
\title{Provably Efficient Exploration in Reinforcement Learning}
\author{Ishfaq, Haque}
\date{}
\begin{document}


\maketitle

Text goes here. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try removing the fullpage package

Comment: Thanks. while it resolves the issue it makes the gap between header and starting line of first page way too big.

Comment: You would then need to remove the \maketitle command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the head separation:

```
\setlength{\headsep}{15pt} % Adjust the space between header and text
```

It sets the distance between the bottom of the header and the top of the text body.
Before header separation:
[image]

After header separation:
[image]

You can also adjust header height:

```
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt} % Adjust the header height
```

This sets the height of the header. If the header content is larger than the allocated space, it can overlap with the main text.
You can still use the full page package if you desire with the above.